# Warning when switching to another screen if the user has authorization

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When I open the application and if the `isAuth` variable is true, it means the user has authorization, then I want to go to the provider screen.

My authorization component.

```
export const LoginScreen: NavigationStackScreenComponent<NavigationParams> = observer(({ navigation }: NavigationParams) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        AuthState.checkAuthentication();
    }, []);

    if (AuthState.isAuth) {
        navigation.navigate('Provider');
    }

    return <View style={styles.body}>{LoaderState.loading ? <LoaderComponent /> : <AuthComponent />}</View>;
});
```

My provider component.

```
export const ProvidersScreen: NavigationStackScreenComponent<NavigationParams> = observer(({ navigation }: NavigationParams) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        ProvidersState.setProviders();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            {LoaderState.loading ? (
                <LoaderComponent />
            ) : (
                <ItemListComponent itemsList={ProvidersState.providersList} />
            )}
        </View>
    );
});
```

But I get a warning. I understand that it is associated with the `react-navigation` library.
[image]

How to switch to another screen using a conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

Functional components are basically the equivalent to the `render()` function in class components. You are calling `navigate` before the component gets render and that's a problem.

You can either call the `navigate` inside your `useEffect` or put the conditional logic in the parent view.

In the first case, `navigate` will be called AFTER the component renders

```
useEffect(() => {
    AuthState.checkAuthentication();
    if (AuthState.isAuth) {
        navigation.navigate('Provider');
    }
}, []);
```

so it will be visible for half a second and then change. If you'd like to avoid this, then go for the second option.

You can put the condition in the parent. Something like

```
<View>{AuthState.isAuth ? <ProvidersScreen /> : <LoginScreen />}</View>
```